# Eclipse ctrl+Shift+G not working as expected

Tags: eclipse

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> used to find references to the current selection within ALL projects in my Workspace.

Now is seems to only return references within the current Project.

Details:
I have 3 projects in the same database.  1 project is common code. The other 2 projects include the source folder of the common code on the build path.  I prefer to link to common source instead of including the common code as a Project on the build path because then when I deploy by exporting WAR each project has its own self-contained version of the common code.

However <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> seems to work when I include the common code as a Project.  So it looks like I need to do both.  I just don't know why the searching results have changed.  I did install JBoss Tools and as a result of Jboss needed to install a newer version of Indigo.

[Similar issue](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/366695/892914/#msg_892914), but no good answer.

EDIT:
Open two editors with a common class file, one from the linked source folder and one for the actual project folder. When the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> is performed on the linked source, only references with in the project containing the linked folder are found. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> from the actual common project finds references to all projects in the workspace, when those projects have the common project referenced on the build path.
The problem is when I am in a project and I control click a common code method I am taken to the linked source class file. So then when I do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on that method, I miss all the other projects that reference this common method, because the editor contains the file from the linked source.  This never used behaved this way and used to find all projects that referenced this method regardless of which file (linked or actual) was used.

Comment: Eclipse can package a project as a jar in the dependencies instead of compiling across projects.  I believe your problem will be solved if you do that instead.

Comment: I also make changes to the common code too as I'm working on a project.  For instance I may develop a method that other projects can utilize. Which is why I like to look up references, to see what other projects are referencing. Regardless, why did this problem just appear?  Pretty sure it had worked with linked source folder.

Answer (score 3):

I find the command..It is

```
Ctrl+ALT +G  // search through out workspace
```

not

```
Ctrl +shift +G // searching within class/project
```

**And one tip**

`Ctrl+shift+L` to see all commands in Eclipse

Comment: In my command list, for me Ctrl+ALT +G = Find text In Workspace and Ctrl +shift +G = References in Workspace.  Both are relative to 'WorkSpace'

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if you are using Maven and your version numbers do not match. I had a dependent project with `<version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>` that was being referenced in another project as `<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`. Fixing the mismatch so that versions were correct allowed CTRL-SHIFT-G to find the references in the workspace that it could not find before.